# Remote X session on EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using an Ubuntu Server EBS-based AMI on Amazon EC2. I have installed the desktop packages and ssh -X to my machine using the default ubuntu account but when I enter the command:

```
startx
```

I get the following output:

```
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
```

What do I need to do to get a remote X session running from here?

Comment: Do you actually want a full desktop, or is running individual tools adequate?  What client OS are you connecting from.

Comment: I do want a full desktop. I am connecting from OS X and have successfully run remote desktop sessions from another Ubuntu machine on my LAN.

Comment: Beware programmers carrying screwdrivers...

Comment: @gWaldo There are some programs that can't be run without a screen. (At least as far as I can tell, this is the easiest or only solution `java` `headless-exception`s.)

Answer (score 4):

`startx` is used when you want to run a full X server, which is almost never what you want to do on a remote system. Instead, just run the app directly and ssh will forward the X messages to your local system.

Comment: Even when I use ssh -X -C -i key.pem ubuntu@mymachine to login, I can't get an X session.

Comment: Have you double checked.  Maybe X11 forwarding is disabled in your sshd_config.

Comment: X11 forwarding is set to yes in sshd_config

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you do, indeed have X installed?  One clue would be to see if you have an /etc/X11/xorg.conf (especially if it's not just a blank file)

Also, do you have any GUI apps installed?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo xinit`

Do you have `gnome-desktop-environment` installed?

BTW, you can look through programs to install with `apt-cache search gnome-desktop`. Might be helpful in whatever you're trying to do.